# When adding 0 to cell it changes to NULL in SQL

Tags: sql-server

### Issue

---

I am having a problem when trying to insert a row into my SQL table.

I have a table which has a column called '*SyncTime*' which has a datatype of '*Float*'.  When the application loads a row gets added that looks like the following:

```
--------------------------------------
|   ID   |   SyncTime   |    Date    |
--------------------------------------
|  234   |      -1      | 24/06/2016 |
```

When i click a certain button in my application i update the '*SyncTime*' in the row to '0'. When i do this it changes to NULL:

```
--------------------------------------
|   ID   |   SyncTime   |    Date    |
--------------------------------------
|  234   |     NULL     | 24/06/2016 |
```

What i want the row to look like is:

```
--------------------------------------
|   ID   |   SyncTime   |    Date    |
--------------------------------------
|  234   |       0      | 24/06/2016 |
```

Comment: Then show us the code which possibly could cause this bug. So which contains `UPDATE TableName SET SyncTime  = @SyncTime WHERE ID = @ID`

Comment: Start by doing `ALTER TABLE Table MODIFY SyncTime FLOAT NOT NULL` ...

Comment: And this can't be tagged mysql AND sql-server.  Pick one

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Incorrect syntax with MODIFY.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter: if `NULL` is allowed this doesn't help.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I will get this code now.

Comment: @BenClarke that was for mysql. You can google the sql-server syntax yourself since you had both tagged originally.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter `alter table Table alter column SyncTime FLOAT NOT NULL`

Comment: @BenClarke show up your `CODE` fot update